# MQTT: Does paho store failed outbound messages

Tags: java, mqtt, paho

We are building a project in Java which is using MQTT to communicate with other services using Paho client library. While running the application, I observed that if the broker is down, Paho is not caching failed outbound messages.

Is there a way to make Paho cache failed outbound messages?

I am using Paho version 1.2.5

```
org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3:1.2.5
```

Here is how I have configured it:

```
public void connect(MqttCallback mqttCallback, int maxInflight) {
        try {
            persistence = new MqttDefaultFilePersistence(mqttPersistenceLocation);
            mqttClient = new MqttAsyncClient(broker, clientId, persistence);

            connOpts = new MqttConnectOptions();

            // always set cleanSession to false if QoS 1 or 2 is used.
            connOpts.setCleanSession(false);
            connOpts.setAutomaticReconnect(true);
            connOpts.setMaxInflight(maxInflight);

            mqttClient.setCallback(mqttCallback);

            LOGGER.info("Connecting to broker: " + broker + " with maxInflight: " + maxInflight);

            mqttClient.connect(connOpts).waitForCompletion();

            LOGGER.info("Connected");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("Error while connecting to MQTT:" + e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: .... ***if the broker is done*** ... what do you mean with this??

Comment: [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65948384/edit) the question to show which version of the Paho client you are using and how you have configured it. Offline Buffering is listed as supported option on the library's [page](https://www.eclipse.org/paho/index.php?page=clients/java/index.php#)

Comment: I wanted to say *... if the brokre is down...* corrected that now. Also, I added version of Paho I am using

Comment: You haven't shown how you've configured it